# Custom drawing invisible until quit

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, cgcontext

In my subclass of UIView, custom drawing. The original drawing works fine, i.e. when triggered from `viewDidLoad` or else from a swipe or shake gesture, which clears the screen and redraws.

The problem comes when I try to draw **on top of** what's already there-- it behaves erratically, usually **invisible** and **offset** from where I've placed it, but then **it appears if I press the home button**. On home-button press, as the view disappears I get a glimpse of what I've tried to draw. If I relaunch the app all the drawing is there. What gives?

Here's how I'm set up:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect; {
    cgRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    cgSize = cgRect.size;
        context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    for (int i=0; i<(cgSize.width / spacing); i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<(cgSize.height / spacing); j++) {
            [self drawObjectAtPosX:i*spacing andY:j*spacing withId:i*(cgSize.height / spacing) + j];
         }
     }
```

There are invisible buttons over certain objects. When they are pressed, the object is to be redrawn in a different color:

```
-(void)buttonPressed:theButton {
int which = [theButton tag];
if ([[objectArray objectAtIndex:which] shouldBeRedrawn]) {
        [self redrawObjectforID:which];
    }
}

-(void)redrawObjectforID:(int)which {
        myObject *chosenOne = [objectArray objectAtIndex:which];
        CGFloat m_x = chosenOne.x;
        CGFloat m_y = chosenOne.y;
        context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 205/255.0,173/255.0,0.0,1.0); // LINE color
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 205/255.0,197/255.0,0.0,1.0); // FILL color
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, m_x, m_y);
        CGContextRotateCTM(context, chosenOne.rotation);
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            [self drawObjectSegmentatX:m_x andY:m_y forID:which inContext:context]; // custom drawing stuff
            CGContextRotateCTM(context, radians(90));
        } 
        CGContextRotateCTM(context, -chosenOne.rotation);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -m_x, -m_y);
}
```

Comment: UPDATE: the drawing from `buttonPressed` appears to be mirrored over the y-axis as well (once it appears, naturally). Could there be some kind of switch I'm accidentally doing between a drawing context (y = 0 means bottom) and a bitmap context (y = 0 means top)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own, but here's what I learned today:

**All custom drawing needs to be in `DrawRect`**. The glitchy behavior I was seeing was the result of `DrawRect` being called by the view disappearing or being reinstated. Moved, and it works.

Location of the custom redraw is still off, but that's another question.